# Making a SortedList readonly

Tags: c#, dictionary, sortedlist

I often have classes exposing lists as `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`s, i.e.

```
public class Class
{
  List<string> list;

  public ReadOnlyCollection<string> TheList
  {
    get { return list.AsReadOnly(); }
  }
}
```

What's the best way to do this for an `IDictionary<T,U>` such as a `SortedList<string, string>`?

Comment: Interfaces have nothing to do with implementation. `IDictionary<T,U>` provides write-methods by definition. So you just cannot remove them from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> sourceDictionary;

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys
    {
        get { return sourceDictionary.Keys; }
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> Values
    {
        get { return sourceDictionary.Values; }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return sourceDictionary[key]; }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return sourceDictionary.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public ReadOnlyDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> sourceDictionary)
    {
        AssertUtilities.ArgumentNotNull(sourceDictionary, "sourceDictionary");

        this.sourceDictionary = sourceDictionary;
    }

    void IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return sourceDictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    bool IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Remove(TKey key)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return sourceDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Clear()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return sourceDictionary.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        sourceDictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return sourceDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)sourceDictionary).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

[Edit]
@Simon Buchan and @Cory Nelson pointed out that it is better to use implicit interface implementation for those methods that are not supported. Updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Cheers, I think I'll do this with the alteration of inheriting from `ReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`

Comment: @Matthew Finlay - I suggest not to do this. You will lose the power of dictionary, like optimized search.

Comment: @Alex, just curious, why do you include `Add()/Remove()/Clear()` and throw NSE's? Why not just leave them out all together?

Comment: @jb - if you have usages that by accident use those methods, you would rather prefer to crash so you know about the bug, rather than have subtle bugs.

Comment: You should make the unsupported methods private.

Comment: @Cory - seriously? :) those methods are part of IDictionary<TKey, TValue> interface. Can you show me how to make those methods private? I would really like to know.

Comment: The same way you made IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() private.

Comment: @Cory - GetEnumerator it is not private. This is explicit interface implementation. Nothing stops anybody from calling GetEnumearator.

Comment: Nothing stops people from calling it, but they must call it through IEnumerable.  Using the class directly, the method won't be available.

Comment: @Cory - if you're saying that it is better to use explicit interface implementation in this case, then I agree. You said to make it private - this didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Simon Buchan - I agree with this, and I said this in my last post :). Will update the answer to make all the folks happy.

Comment: @Alex: Nitpicking - explicitly implemented members are, in fact, private according to spec. Check with `Type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)`. EDIT: yeah, I didn't refresh and see those comments, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ReadOnlyDictionary class that implements IDictionary as a wrapper around an internal Dictionary instance.  For the methods that would modify the dictionary, throw an exception.  Implement IsReadOnly to return true.  Implement all other methods to pass through to the internal Dictionary instance.

Comment: I think that throwing an exception is not a good idea, since it is a runtime event.

Comment: I'd also reccommend making IsReadOnly and the modifying methods explicit interface implementations to match ReadOnlyCollection: `bool IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }`. You can explicitly implement the indexer setter if you forward the getter to the implicit getter: `TValue IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.this[TKey key] { get { return this[key]; } set { throw InvalidOperationException(); } }`

Comment: @zerkms: ReadOnlyCollection throws `NotSupportedException("Collection is read-only.")` on it's explicit implementations.

Comment: @Simon Buchan: yes, and it is not a static check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with standard LINQ methods.

1. Create you source list:

   ```
    List<String> myList = new List<String>() { "A", "B", "C" };
   ```
2. Project your list into a dictionary using `.ToDictionary` linq extension method:

   ```
    var myDictionary = myList.ToDictionary(listItem => listItem);
   ```

Note: The lambda expression peeks a key from you list (rembember that dictionary can only contain unique keys; otherwise consider the use of `ILookup` which represents a dictionary of list).

3. Reform your dictionary to a SortedDictionary instance:

   ```
    var mySortedDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(myDictionary);
   ```
4. Expose your sorted dictionary as an `IReadOnlyDictionary` interface as follows:

   ```
    public IReadOnlyDictionary MemberDictionary { get; private set; );

    // ...somewhere in your constructor or class's initialization method...
    this.MemberDictionary = mySortedDictionary;
   ```